# Local coordinates inside a cube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Robot arm ( collider is the movable area )

[image]

Illustration of problem

[image]

I am making a virtual clone of a robot arm and need it to move to coordinates inside a cube (movable area). The robot arm is controlled with three values right now, x,y and z. These values can bring the head of the robot arm to all four corners of the cube. the values go from 0 to 100. I need a vector3 in unitys world space to be converted to these values inside the cube. I'm doing it this way so that the whole robot prefab can be moved and rotated without breaking this function. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Comment: There are infinitely many vector 3 inside your cube. Your question is not very clear. If you want to check if a point is inside the cube then just calculate min and max x,y and z values then check if the point belongs to these [bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html). If that is not what you are asking please clarify your question.

Comment: @AliKanat Sorry if it wasn't clear enough I added a picture

Comment: I still don't get it. So do you have a Target position already? What does it have to do with local coordinates. Are you trying to find this target? If so based on what?

Comment: I have the target position in world coordinates. I am looking for the target position coordinates inside the cube. So the world coordinates could be (-2.65, 3.45, -12.8) but inside the cube they would be ( 26, 50, 34 ) because the cube has 0 to 100 on each axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a simple cube than all you need to know is it's edge size and do something like

```
// Set this e.g. in the Inspector
// or somewhere get it e.g. in Start like
// edgesize = transform.lossyScale.x;
public float edgesize;

public Vector3 RobotToUnityPosition(Vector3 input)
{
    var output = input;

    // first shift the values in order to map the values (0 to 100) to
    // (-50 to +50) 
    output -= Vector3.one * 50.0f;

    // now eliminate the factor 100
    // so you get (-0.5 to +0.5)
    output /= 100.0f;

    // finally scale it accordingly to the cube's edgesize
    // so get it mapped to (-0.5 * edgesize to +0.5 * edgesize)
    output *= edgesize;

    return output;

    // could ofcourse also be done in one line like
    return ((input - Vector3.one * 50) / 100.0f) * edgesize;
}

public Vector3Int UnityToRobotPosition(Vector3 input)
{
    // basically do it the other way round
    var output = input;

    // Get percentages
    // (-0.5 to +0.5)
    output /= edgesize;

    // scale it up to factor 100
    // (-50 to +50)
    output *= 100.0f;

    // shift the values back
    // (0 to 100)
    output += Vector3.one * 50.0f;

    // Until here you also could have done it again in one line like
    //var output = (intput / edgesize) * 100.0f + Vector3.one * 50.0f;

    // Now you might want to clamp the values
    output.x = Mathf.Clamp(output.x, 0, 100);
    output.y = Mathf.Clamp(output.y, 0, 100);
    output.z = Mathf.Clamp(output.z, 0, 100);

    // Finally you might want to get it as Vector3Int ? 
    // if not you can skip that and change the return type to Vector3
    return Vector3Int.FloorToInt(output);
}
```

Demo (I added some stuff only to demonstrate how it works)

[image]

---

Here is the full code I used if you want to use it as a startpoint

```
public class PositionConverter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float edgesize;

    public Vector3 inputVector;
    // I used a transform here in order to simply drag around
    // the object in Unity (or set it via script)
    public Transform WorldSpacePosition;
    public Vector3 backtoRobot;

    // whether to automatically update backtoRobot using the WorldSpacePosition.localPosition;
    public bool autoupdate;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // I simply used the lossyScale.x as edgeSize
        edgesize = transform.lossyScale.x;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(!autoupdate)return;

        UpdateRobotPosition();
    }

    // Just fancy stuff for being able to call that method via
    // the context menu
    [ContextMenu("UpdateWorldPosition")]
    private void UpdateWorldPosition()
    {
        WorldSpacePosition.localPosition = RobotToUnityPosition(inputVector);
    }

    // Just fancy stuff for being able to call that method via
    // the context menu
    [ContextMenu("UpdateRobotPosition")]
    private void UpdateRobotPosition()
    {
        backtoRobot = UnityToRobotPosition(WorldSpacePosition.localPosition);
    }

    public Vector3 RobotToUnityPosition(Vector3 input)
    {
        var output = input;

        // first shift the values since 0 means e.g. -x edge etc
        output.x -= Vector3.one * 50.0f;

        // eliminate the factor 100
        output /= 100.0f;

        // scale it according to the cube's edgesize
        output *= edgesize;

        return output;
    }

    public Vector3Int UnityToRobotPosition(Vector3 input)
    {
        // basically do it the other way round
        var output = input;

        // Get percentages
        output /= edgesize;

        // scale it up to factor 100
        output *= 100;

        // shift the values back
        output += Vector3.one * 50.0f;

        // you might want to clamp the values
        output.x = Mathf.Clamp(output.x, 0, 100);
        output.y = Mathf.Clamp(output.y, 0, 100);
        output.z = Mathf.Clamp(output.z, 0, 100);

        // you might want to get it as Vector3Int ? 
        // if not you can skip that and change the return type to Vector3
        return Vector3Int.FloorToInt(output);
    }

    // Just for drawing the WireCube for the bounds
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        edgesize = transform.lossyScale.x;
        Gizmos.matrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix;

        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(Vector3.zero, Vector3.one * edgesize);
    }
}
```

- Add it to an empty `GameObject` and set the scale how you want it in the `Transform`
- Add a child e.g. a Sphere object and reference it as `WorldSpacePosition`

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! I will test it now

Comment: really having trouble trying to implement this

Comment: did you checkout the bottom? I added the full code I used for the demo gif

Comment: Yes sorry, this is an amazing solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have one more question if you don't mind. Is there an easy way to specify the location of each corner of this cube ?

Comment: @DarraghHayes what do you mean exactly?

Comment: if you look at the image I attached of the robot arm in the unity scene you see my cube is actually shorter on one side

Comment: uuhm that looks more complicated I'm sorry .. my answer was under the assumption you have a primitive form such as a real cube or at least a Cuboid .. right now there comes no quick fix to my mind in order to apply this to a form you have there ... maybe you could open a new question specific to this including the info what we have so far ... looks more like a maths problem.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple enough. You can use the Transform component to perform calculations in any objects local space.

```
// constants (choose as they fit your scene)
Vector3 cubeSize = new Vector3(100, 100, 100);
Vector3 cubePivotLocal = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

// The actual calculation
Vector3 worldPos = (your target world position);
Vector3 localPos = Vector3.Scale((transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPos) - cubePivotLocal), cubeSize);

// localPos contains position of the target point in the local space of the script holder (your robot)
```

All transformations (translations, rotations, scaling) of the script holder and its parent (grandparent, ...) are taken into account.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment but if you look at the picture I just added I'm not sure how I could utilize this method.

Comment: When you say "the values go from 0 to 100", do you mean actuall coordinates in local space? If you put a child object into the cube and set its coordinates to 0/0/0 and then to 100/100/100, will that position it on the cube's corners? If so, then the localPos calculated in my example will give you exactly the coordinates you're looking for. If so desired, you can easily clamp them into the 0-100 range yourself.

Comment: "I need a vector3 in unitys world space to be converted to these values inside the cube". The one calculation I provide is all you need. `localPos` contains the wanted result. It may need to be scaled from 0-1 range up to 0-100 range, and maybe given an offset, but I can't provide you that unless you specify your requirements more clearly.